# JMS message processing with spring integration in cloud environment

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-integration-jdbc

I'm currently trying to refactor the processing of JMS messages to work in a distributed/cloud environment. To allow a better retry and error handling the messages are first stored to the database with a JPA entity and then read by spring integration jpa inbound adapter. This works fine as long as just a single instance of my service is running. However when multiple instances are running, the instances try to process the same message even after introducing a processing state on the persisted messages.

I have already tried to save the JMS messages in a JDBC message store, however then I would have to define a group identifier according to which an instance could select a message which is not really possible since the number of instances is dynamic and I can not assign a group id for each instance. Another possibility could be some kind of distributed lock with a LockRegistry but I couldn't make that work.

Do you have any hint/advice how I could implement the following requirements the best with spring integration:

- JMS message should be persisted
- Any instance can pick up the message and process it
- If the processing fails there will be a retry for x times (could also be retried by another instance)
- If an instance crashes or gets killed during the processing the message must not be lost

Is there maybe some spring-cloud component which could be helpful? 
I'm happy about every hint in which direction I should go.

Comment: Why not just use JMS directly? Using RDBMS as a message queue is an anti-pattern and JMS supports your use case implicitly.

Comment: This is what I had originally but I couldn't really control the retry behavior. During the processing I have to make calls to other services which might not be available and the processing can not be done so I would like to wait some time before retrying. However failing and rolling back in the JMSListener leads to instantly reading the same message again.

Comment: It's not part of the JMS spec, but some brokers support adding a delay before a message is retried. e.g [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html). Check your broker's documentation.

Comment: We are using IBM MQ and I checked with the responsible team here and they told me that would not be possible with IBM MQ. Thats why I went for the solution with storing it in the DB.